# Node with Fusionauth passport-oauth OAuth2Strategy Error: Failed to obtain access token

Tags: node.js, fusionauth

I'm trying to authorize my node application via fusionauth with passport and express and
I'm getting a node error from the fusionauth Callback "Failed to obtain access token" after login to fusionauth. I'm not sure why the fusionauth response doesn't include the token?

fusionauth authorize link with callback
***fusion_auth_server:9011/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Foauth2%2Fcallback&client_id=42a5####-####-####-####-########***

````
 name: 'InternalOAuthError',
  message: 'Failed to obtain access token',
  oauthError:
   { Error: connect EHOSTUNREACH 0.0.35.51:80 - Local (192.168.1.46:62475)
       at internalConnect (net.js:872:16)
       at defaultTriggerAsyncIdScope (internal/async_hooks.js:294:19)
       at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.emitLookup [as callback] (net.js:1019:9)
       at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:61:10)
     errno: 'EHOSTUNREACH',
     code: 'EHOSTUNREACH',
     syscall: 'connect',
     address: '0.0.35.51',
     port: 80 } }

```
app.get('/oauth2/authorize', oauth2.authorize);
app.get('/oauth2/callback', oauth2.callback);
app.get('/oauth2/logout', oauth2.logout);

```

```
const passport = require('passport');
const OAuth2Strategy = require('passport-oauth').OAuth2Strategy;
const http = require('http');
const config = {
    "apiKey": "63353861-####-####-####-##########",
    "callbackURL": "http://localhost:3000/oauth2/callback",
    "clientID": "42a5bc23-####-####-####-#####",
    "clientSecret": "WI2Y04lkozWonBeRz_####################",
    "host": "fusion_auth_server", 
    "port": "9011"
    };

passport.use(
  'fusionauth',
  new OAuth2Strategy(
    {
      authorizationURL: `${config.host}:${config.port}/oauth2/authorize`,
      tokenURL: `${config.host}:${config.port}/oauth2/token`,
      clientID: config.clientID,
      clientSecret: config.clientSecret,
      callbackURL: config.callbackURL
    },
    function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
      // verify accessToken was provided`enter code here`
      if (!accessToken) {
        done(null, false);
      }

      // verify token and get user info
      const options = {
        host: config.host,
        port: config.port,
        path: '/oauth2/userinfo',
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`
        }
      };
      const userInfoRequest = http.get(options, res => {
        var chunks = '';
        res.on('data', data => {
          chunks += data;
        });
        res.on('end', () => {
          if (res.statusCode === 200) {
            const result = JSON.parse(chunks);
            const user = {
              ...result,
              accessToken
            };

            // todo: persist user

            done(null, user);
          } else {
            done(null, false);
          }
        });
      });
      userInfoRequest.end();
    }
  )
);

const callback = (req, res, next) => {
    //console.log("callback",res)
  passport.authenticate('fusionauth', (err, user) => {
     console.log("Authenticating",err)
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    if (!user) {
      return res.redirect('http://localhost:4200/login');
    }
   // console.log(user);
    res.cookie('accessToken', user.accessToken, { httpOnly: true });
    res.redirect('http://localhost:4200');
  })(req, res, next);
};

module.exports = {

  authorize: passport.authenticate('fusionauth', {
    session: false
  }),
  callback,
  logout: (req, res) => {
    req.logout();
    res.redirect('http://localhost:4200/');
  }
};


```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like some kind of network error, would be my first guess. `Error: connect EHOSTUNREACH 0.0.35.51:80`. That's a weird ip address.

I see the config host is `fusion_auth_server`. Does that resolve to that IP address?

Comment: I agree it's odd, and I just replaced ***fusion_auth_server*** for this post the actual one does resolve. I'm thinking it might be firewall related?

Comment: but the ***fusion_auth_server*** isn't 0.0.35.51:80

Comment: Hmmm. Weird. This looks like it might be a clue: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1514 . I'd google for that ip address and see if it's something in your network.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the token **http://** in front of it to resolve to the correct IP

Changed the following line:
From:

```
tokenURL: `${config.host}:${config.port}/oauth2/token`,
```

To:

```
tokenURL: `http://${config.host}:${config.port}/oauth2/token`,
```